# PHP variables not getting overwritten on subsequent queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

## The Situation

I'm fairly new to object-oriented programming in PHP and currently I'm creating a small CMS for learning purposes. I've learned a lot about OOP on my way, but I'm facing a weird issue at the moment. I've created a Singleton class to deal with the database connection and queries.

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if(!isset(self::$instance))
    {
        self::$instance = new Database();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}
```

In the same class, there also is a method to execute queries. It takes two parameters, the query and an optional array with parameters to bind for the prepared statements. You can see its source below.

```
public function execute($query, $params = array())
{
    $this->error = false; // Set 'error' to false at the start of each query.

    if($this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($query))
    {
        if(!empty($params))
        {
            $index = 1;
            foreach($params as $parameter)
            {
                $this->query->bindValue($index, $parameter);
                ++$index;
            }
        }

        if($this->query->execute())
        {
            $this->results = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->count = $this->query->rowCount();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

## The Problem

If I have multiple queries on the same page, the `results` and `count` variables still contain the values of the first query. Imagine the following - the first query retrieves all users from my database. Let's say there are 15. The second query retrieves all blog posts from the database, let's say there are none. If no posts are present, I want to display a message, otherwise I run a loop to display all results. In this case, the loop is executed even though there are no blog posts, because the `count` variable is used to determine if there are posts in the database and it still holds the 15 from the first query somehow.

This obviously leads to some errors. Same with `results`. It still holds the value from the first query.

```
$query = Database::getInstance()->execute('SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_id DESC');

if(!$query->countRes())
{
    echo '<h2>There are no blog posts in the database.</h2>';
}
else
{
    foreach($query->results() as $query)
    {
        echo '<article>
                <h3>'.$query->article_heading.'</h3>
                <p>'.$query->article_preview.'</p>
              </article>';
    }
}
```

The `countRes()` and `results()` methods simply return the variables from the DB class.

I hope that I have explained the problem understandable. Responses are very appreciated.

Comment: Oh gawd please don't put spaces around `->`

Comment: Okay, I edited my post and removed them.

Comment: Are you sure `prepare()` is succeeding for the second query? If it fails, the rest of the code in `execute` will be skipped, so the variables will not be updated. Make sure you have error signalling enabled for PDO.

Comment: What if this fails? `if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($query))`? It's good that you're checking the return code, but you need to better handle the case that that occurs.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the results from the first call at the end? Or do you maybe have the results of the last call in the beginning (i.e. do all queries at the top and use them later)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a response object to avoid attaching query specific data to the global database object.

Example:

```
<?php

class PDO_Response {
    protected $count;
    protected $results;
    protected $query;
    protected $error;
    protected $success = true;


    public function __construct($query){
        $this->query = $query;
        try{
           $this->query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e;
            $this->success = false;


        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCount(){
        if( is_null( $this->count ) ){
            $this->count = $this->query->rowCount();
        }
        return $this->count;
    }

    public function getResults(){
        if( is_null( $this->results ) ){
            $this->results = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        return $this->results;
    }

    public function success(){
        return $this->success;
    }

    public function getError(){
        return $this->error;
    }
}
```

Then in your database class:

```
public function execute($query, $params = array())
{
    if($this -> _query = $this -> _pdo -> prepare($query))
    {
        if(!empty($params))
        {
            $index = 1;

            foreach($params as $parameter)
            {
                $this -> _query -> bindValue($index, $parameter);
                ++$index;
            }
        }

        return new PDO_Response($this->_query);
    }

    throw new Exception('Some error text here');
}
```

**UPDATE**: Moved execution into response class for error handling

Example usage (not tested)

```
$select = $database->execute('SELECT * FROM table');

if( $select->success() ){
    //query succeeded - do what you want with the response
    //SELECT
    $results = $select->getResults();
}

$update = $database->execute('UPDATE table SET col = "value"');

if( $update->success() ){
   //cool, the update worked
}
```

This will help fix your issue in the event that subsequent queries fail, there will not be any old query data attached to the database object.

Comment: This doesn't answer op's question as to why his/her approach isn't working.

Comment: That's right but it sounds like a decent solution to me. Is there anything wrong with that kind of approach?

Comment: The last line I added explains how this approach will keep you from getting stale data in your new response. The main difference with this approach is you can't keep chaining new database calls from your response object. You have now separated the two. You would have one $database object that would return a $response object.

Comment: If you wanted to take it a step further I would suggest creating models. A model is an object that represents a table in your database specifically. For instance you could create an Article model, that would be responsible for holding data from the articles table. Generally 1 row per model.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Isn't the `if($this->_query->execute())` still required though?

Comment: Yep, left that out. Sorry. Editing original answer to reflect that

Comment: Another clarification, you may end up with a completely empty response object if the query executes successfully but returns no results. However you won't face the problem of having old data where you expect new data.

Comment: Just updated the response object to be a bit smarter. Not sure if i've over stepped it's concerns by adding query execution, but that's a basic idea of how it could work.

Comment: Inserts and updates are working fine now. Thanks for the great solution! :)